# svn tree conflicts: what am i doing wrong?

Tags: svn, merge, tree-conflict

Anytime I try to merge in SVN I get piles of tree conflicts.  Well, in the case of this sample script just one, but still.

```
#!/bin/bash
svnadmin create repo
svn checkout file://`pwd`/repo wc
cd wc
mkdir trunk branches
svn add trunk branches
svn commit -m 'created trunk and branches'
echo red > trunk/colors
svn add trunk/colors
svn commit trunk -m 'created trunk/colors with red inside'
svn copy trunk branches/a
svn commit branches/a -m 'created branches/a'
echo green >> trunk/colors
svn commit trunk -m 'added green to trunk/colors'
echo blue >> branches/a/colors
svn commit branches/a -m 'added blue to branches/a/colors'
svn update
svn merge ^/trunk branches/a
```

My result is:

```
Checked out revision 0.
A         trunk
A         branches
Adding         branches
Adding         trunk

Committed revision 1.
A         trunk/colors
Adding         trunk/colors
Transmitting file data .
Committed revision 2.
A         branches/a
Adding         branches/a
Adding         branches/a/colors

Committed revision 3.
Sending        trunk/colors
Transmitting file data .
Committed revision 4.
Sending        branches/a/colors
Transmitting file data .
Committed revision 5.
Updating '.':
At revision 5.
--- Merging r2 through r5 into 'branches/a':
   C branches/a/colors
--- Recording mergeinfo for merge of r2 through r5 into 'branches/a':
 U   branches/a
Summary of conflicts:
  Tree conflicts: 1
```

I know that SVN isn't known for being merge friendly, but I have to assume that in this case it is my fault somehow.  Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem you've encountered is not due to the 'local copy'[1] per se.  The problem lies in the fact that, in revision 3, you copy a mixed-revision working copy (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.basic.in-action.mixedrevs).

If we run your script right up until you copy 'trunk' to 'branches/a' we find that we have a mixed-revision working copy:

```
>svn st -v
                 0        0  ?           .
                 1        1 pburba       branches
                 1        1 pburba       trunk
                 2        2 pburba       trunk\colors
```

So when you copy 'trunk' to 'branches/a', you are actually copying trunk@1 and trunk/colors@2:

```
>svn copy trunk branches\a
A         branches\a

>svn st -v
                 0        0  ?           .
                 1        1 pburba       branches
A  +             -        1 pburba       branches\a
A  +             -        2 pburba       branches\a\colors
                 1        1 pburba       trunk
                 2        2 pburba       trunk\colors

>svn ci -m "Copy mixed-rev trunk"
Adding         branches\a
Adding         branches\a\colors

Committed revision 3.
```

We can see this most clearly when looking at the verbose log for r3:

```
>svn log -v -r3
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r3 | pburba | 2013-03-11 15:31:23 -0400 (Mon, 11 Mar 2013) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /branches/a (from /trunk:1)
   A /branches/a/colors (from /trunk/colors:2)

Copy mixed-rev trunk
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Skipping ahead to the problematic merge, we have a "clean" working copy with no mixed-revisions and no local modifications.  So far so good:

```
>svn st -v
                 5        5 pburba       .
                 5        5 pburba       branches
                 5        5 pburba       branches\a
                 5        5 pburba       branches\a\colors
                 5        4 pburba       trunk
                 5        4 pburba       trunk\colors
```

But if we use the svn mergeinfo command to preview what revisions will be merged we notice that revsion 2 is eligible:

```
>svn mergeinfo --show-revs eligible ^/trunk branches\a
r2
r4
```

But wait, revison 2 is the addition of 'colors',

```
>svn log -v -r2
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2 | pburba | 2013-03-11 15:43:52 -0400 (Mon, 11 Mar 2013) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /trunk/colors

created trunk/colors with red inside
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and we already copied that when we created the branch in revision 3!  So why is Subversion trying to merge it again?  The reason comes back to the mixed-revision WC-to-WC copy we made.  The merge target 'branch/a' knows that it was copied from trunk@1, prior to the addition of 'trunk/colors'.  So the merge thinks that revision 2 hasn't been been merged to branch/a and tries to merge this change, adding 'colors' into a 'a' where a file of the same name already exists, which results in a *tree* conflict:

```
>svn merge ^/trunk branches\a
--- Merging r2 through r5 into 'branches\a':
   C branches\a\colors
--- Recording mergeinfo for merge of r2 through r5 into 'branches\a':
 U   branches\a
Summary of conflicts:
  Tree conflicts: 1

>svn st
 M      branches\a
      C branches\a\colors
      >   local file obstruction, incoming file add upon merge
Summary of conflicts:
  Tree conflicts: 1
```

So we tricked Subversion with our mixed-revision WC-to-WC copy, which effectively brought revision 2 to the branch during the copy.  So why can't Subversion detect this and skip revision 2?  In this case we conceivably could do that, but what if revision 2 included other changes to 'trunk'?  e.g.:

```
>svn log -v -r2
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2 | pburba | 2013-03-11 15:43:52 -0400 (Mon, 11 Mar 2013) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /trunk/colors
   A /trunk/README
   M /trunk

created trunk/colors with red inside, add a README file, and set the
svn:ignore property on trunk
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Subversion doesn't support merging *part* of a revision to a given path, it's either all-or-nothing.

~~~~~

So how to avoid this problem?  As you've already discovered, doing a URL-to-URL copy solves it.  Why?  Because when the copy source is a URL, it is, by definition, at some uniform revision:

```
>svn log -v -r3
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r3 | pburba | 2013-03-11 16:02:59 -0400 (Mon, 11 Mar 2013) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /branches/a (from /trunk:2)

Create branch 'a' from 'trunk' with a URL-to-URL copy.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However you can also accomplish the same thing with a URL-to-WC copy:

```
 svn commit trunk -m 'created trunk/colors with red inside'
-svn copy trunk branches/a
+svn copy ^/trunk branches/a
 svn commit branches/a -m 'created branches/a'
```

Or simply by updating the WC prior to the WC-to-WC copy in your original script:

```
 svn commit trunk -m 'created trunk/colors with red inside'
+svn update
 svn copy trunk branches/a
 svn commit branches/a -m 'created branches/a'
```

Your original solution, the URL-to-URL copy followed by an update, is the best option IMO.  The update & WC-to-WC copy and the URL-to-WC copy both allow for the possibility that additional changes can be made to the copy before it is committed -- it's best that the revision in which a branch is created has no other changes besides the copy.  That said, all of these option will work fine[2].

[1] In Subversion-speak we usually refer to this as a working-copy-to-working-copy copy, or WC-to-WC copy for short.  Contrast this with URL-to-URL, URL-to-WC, or WC-to-URL copies.  WC-to-URL copies are also vulnerable to the problem described above.  See also 'svn copy --help'.

[2] Of course even using one of these three options still results in a *text* conflict, but that is expected since we made incompatible changes to the 'colors' file on both trunk and the branch after the branch was created.

```
>svn merge ^/trunk branches\a
--- Merging r3 through r5 into 'branches\a':
C    branches\a\colors
--- Recording mergeinfo for merge of r3 through r5 into 'branches\a':
 U   branches\a
Summary of conflicts:
  Text conflicts: 1
Conflict discovered in file 'branches\a\colors'.
Select: (p) postpone, (df) diff-full, (e) edit, (m) merge,
        (mc) mine-conflict, (tc) theirs-conflict, (s) show all options: p

>svn st
 M      branches\a
C       branches\a\colors
?       branches\a\colors.merge-left.r2
?       branches\a\colors.merge-right.r5
?       branches\a\colors.working
Summary of conflicts:
  Text conflicts: 1
```

Comment: Superb explanation.  You will certainly be a tremendous asset to SO.  :]

Comment: VERY useful! you should say, though, that this is **different** from `sync back from a branch to trunk`, once it's ready. and why you need `--reintegrate` there and why `delete branch` and `copy trunk branch` again must be used once reintegrated (or merge with --record-only). I lost some time wondering.., as I had no mixed revs in branch and trunk  and still had tree conflict :P

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the issue lies in the use of a local `svn copy` rather than remote.

```
-svn copy trunk branches/a
-svn commit branches/a -m 'created branches/a'
+svn copy ^/trunk ^/branches/a -m 'server side copy from trunk to branches/a'
+svn update
```

While [the SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.using.html#svn.branchmerge.using.create) says that the local copy "technique isn't recommended", it does not list this as a reason.  Rather it simply talks about cheap server side copies, disk usage, time, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The case you demonstrated should generate a normal conflict, it should not result in a tree conflict.

I suspect your use case is performing a subtree merge (notice the subtree paths in your svn merge command).
All the mergeinfo stuff is only stored in the top level of your checkout

From 'svn help merge':

```
 SOURCE specifies the branch from where the changes will be pulled, and
 TARGET_WCPATH specifies a working copy of the target branch to which
 the changes will be applied. Normally SOURCE and TARGET_WCPATH should
 each correspond to the root of a branch. (If you want to merge only a
 subtree, then the subtree path must be included in both SOURCE and
 TARGET_WCPATH; this is discouraged, to avoid subtree mergeinfo.)
```

The following snippet shows the functionality I believe you are looking for while avoiding the subtree merge.
It uses the 'svn switch' to avoid the subtree merge and multiple WCs

```
export SVN_REPO=~/svntest
cd $SVN_REPO
rm -rf $SVN_REPO/*
svnadmin create repo
svn mkdir file:///$SVN_REPO/repo/trunk -m "created trunk"
svn mkdir file:///$SVN_REPO/repo/branches -m "created branches"
#
svn checkout file:///$SVN_REPO/repo/trunk wc
cd wc
echo red > colors
svn add colors
svn commit . -m 'created trunk/colors with red inside' 
#
svn cp file:///$SVN_REPO/repo/trunk file:///$SVN_REPO/repo/branches/a  -m 'created branches/a'
#
echo green >> colors
svn commit . -m 'added green to trunk/colors'
#
svn switch file:///$SVN_REPO/repo/branches/a .
echo blue >> colors
svn commit  -m 'added blue to branches/a/colors'
svn update
svn merge file:///$SVN_REPO/repo/trunk
```

Results:

```
Committed revision 1.
SVN_REPO/repo/branches -m "created branches"

Committed revision 2.

SVN_REPO/repo/trunk wc
Checked out revision 2.
 cd wc
 echo red > colors
 svn add colors
 A         colors
 svn commit . -m 'created trunk/colors with red inside'
Adding         colors
Transmitting file data .
Committed revision 3.

SVN_REPO/repo/branches/a  -m 'created branches/a'

Committed revision 4.

 echo green >> colors
 svn commit . -m 'added green to trunk/colors'
Sending        colors
Transmitting file data .
Committed revision 5.

SVN_REPO/repo/branches/a .
 U    colors
Updated to revision 5.
 echo blue >> colors
 svn commit  -m 'added blue to branches/a/colors'
Sending        colors
Transmitting file data .
Committed revision 6.
 svn update
Updating '.':
At revision 6.

Conflict discovered in '/home/jbellamy/svntest/wc/colors'.
Select: (p) postpone, (df) diff-full, (e) edit,
        (mc) mine-conflict, (tc) theirs-conflict,
        (s) show all options: p
--- Merging r4 through r6 into '.':
 C    colors
--- Recording mergeinfo for merge of r4 through r6 into '.':
 U   .
Summary of conflicts:
  Text conflicts: 1
     svn diff
Index: .
===================================================================
--- .   (revision 6)
+++ .   (working copy)

Property changes on: .
___________________________________________________________________
Added: svn:mergeinfo
   Merged /trunk:r4-6
Index: colors
===================================================================
--- colors      (revision 6)
+++ colors      (working copy)
@@ -1,2 +1,6 @@
 red
+<<<<<<< .working
 blue
+=======
+green
+>>>>>>> .merge-right.r6
```

Comment: Your `svn cp` command uses two remotes.  When I updated my script to use remotes for the copy command it worked as well.  Also, my script output specifically shows the merge info being stored to `branches/a`.